# How to ignore 'en' portion in URL - multi-language website

Tags: html, url, redirect, multilingual

I am creating a multi-language site which uses a portion of the URL to determine the language, and **dynamically** fills the page with content using a **PHP array**. I do this so every language has it's own url:

```
 https://website.com/en/home.php
 https://website.com/nl/home.php
```

The issue in this case is that when accessing the english website using **https://website.com/en/home.php**, the site tries to open the file located at the folder:
 
**(root) / > en > home.php**

While the file is actually located at:
 
**(root) / > home.php**

Is it possible to "ignore" the *language portion* in the URL when opening  HTML file, but without redirecting so the user still sees it when they navigate to a page.

I tried using the `<base>` html tag, this did not work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes it is, create a router to do this for you. A router would read your slug and navigate you to the appropriate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a router you can follow the tutorial [here](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/)

You will specifically need to change your .htaccess file to contain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This will redirect all requests to index.php

index.php will need to contain:

```
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
        require __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
    case '/en/home.php' :
        require __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
    case '' :
        require __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
    default:
        require __DIR__ . '/404.php';
        break;
    }
```

This way all requests which are redirected to index.php will show a particular page based on the request url according to what you specify in this router.